# What is the measurement of the angle x in the figure below?

Tags: geometry

For reference: In the figure, ABCD is a parallelogram and $ \measuredangle ABE = 100^o$ , $AE = AD$ and $FC = CD$.
Calculate x.

[image]

My progress:

In this one I couldn't develop much because $FC$ and $EB$ are not parallel...I think the "output" is by some auxiliary construction

[image]

by geogebra

[image]

Comment: You say that $\angle ABE=145$, but your diagram suggests that it is $100$. Is there a typo?

Comment: $\Delta EAB \cong \Delta BCF$ by SAS congruency criterion

Comment: @peta arantes, in figure $\angle ABE=100 ^o$ which one is correct?

Comment: @AlanAbraham..my mistake, thanks for the alert..I've corrected the statement

Comment: @sirous  my mistake, thanks for the alert..I've corrected the statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $\Delta EAB$ and $\Delta BCF$
$\begin{align} 
EA&=BC &(\because AD=BC, \text{ opposite sides of parallelogram})\\
AB&=CF & (\because CD=AB, \text{ opposite sides of parallelogram)}\\
\angle EAB&=\angle BCF=y \text{  (let)} & (\because 90°-\angle BAC=90°-\angle BCD)\\
\therefore \Delta EAB &\cong \Delta BCF &\text{  (by SAS congruency criterion)}\\
\implies \angle EBA&=\angle BFC= 100°&\text{ (corresponding angles of congruent triangles)}\\
\text{and}\qquad EB&=BF &\text{ (corresponding sides of congruent triangles)}\\
\end{align}$

In parallelogram $ABCD$,

$\begin{align}&\angle BAD =90°-y\\
 \implies &\angle ABC=180°-(90°-y)=90°+y \end{align}$

In triangle $BCF$, $\angle FBC= 180°-(100°+y)=80°-y$

In triangle $EBF$, $\angle BEF=\angle BFE=x-100° \; (\because EB=BF)$

$\implies \angle EBF=180°-2(x-100°)=380°-2x$

Sum of all angles around point $B$ $= 100°+(90°+y)+(80°-y)+(380°-2x)=360°$

$\therefore x=145°$

Comment: $\angle EBA= 145°$ is not possible

Comment: @Aman..great resolution.. grateful

Comment: @petaarantes you are welcome

Answer (score 1):

[image]

All you need is to show points F, B, D and C are cyclic, then we have:

$\angle ADB=45$

$\angle FBD=90$

$\rightarrow \angle FAB=35\rightarrow \angle BAD=\angle BCD=55=\angle BFD$

$\Rightarrow \angle ABD=80$

$\angle BFC=55+45=100$

$\angle BEF=45$

$\angle FBE=360-(100+80+90)=90$

$\Rightarrow \angle EFB=45$

Finally:

$x=45+100=145$

Comment: @sirous...EB is not parallel to FC so I don't think it's cyclic..see my last figute..$\rightarrow \angle FAB=35$ I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

Another solution.

[image]

Perform a $90^{\circ}$ clock-wise rotation around $D$ and let the rotated image of $A$ be denoted by $H$. Then $$AD = DH = AE$$ which means that $ADHE$ is a square. If you rotate $90^{\circ}$ counter-clock-wise around $D$ the segment $CD$, you get the segment $GD$ such that $GD = CD$ and $GD \, \perp \, CD$. Hence, $CDGF$ is a square. Because of these new extra constructions, during the $90^{\circ}$ clock-wise rotation around $D$, The points $A$ and $G$ are rotated to the points $H$ and $C$ and consequently, the triangle $ADG$ is rotated to the triangle $HDC$ which means that
$$\angle\, HCD = \angle\, AGD$$
$$HC = AG$$
$$HC \, \perp \, AG$$
Now, if you translate triangle $HDC$ along $DA$  you get as a parallel translated image the triangle $EAB$. Furthermore, if you translate triangle $ADG$ along $AB$  you get as a parallel translated image the triangle $BCF$. Therefore,
$$\angle\, EBA = \angle \, BFC = 100^{\circ}$$
$$EB = FB$$
$$EB \, \perp \, FB$$
Hence, triangle $EBF$ is right-angled and isosceles, which means that $$\angle \, EFB = 45^{\circ}$$
Now putting all these angles together
$$x = \angle \, EFC = \angle\, EFB + \angle \, BFC = 45^{\circ} + 100^{\circ} = 145^{\circ}$$